# How to pass 2d array to a function?

Tags: c, arrays

This code works as it's supposed to do - it prints all ints in the array, but it produces a warning. I would like to know how to do it right and avoid the warning.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

void print_all(int * array, ptrdiff_t num_rows, ptrdiff_t num_cols) {
    for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < num_rows; ++i) {
        for (ptrdiff_t j = 0; j < num_cols; ++j) {
            printf("%d\n", array[num_cols * i + j]);
        }
    }
}


int main() {
    int array[2][4] = {
        {1, 2, 3, 4},
        {5, 6, 7, 8}
    };
    print_all(array, 2, 4);
}
```

This is the warning:

```
$ clang -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fsanitize=address -std=c11 arrays.c
arrays.c:18:15: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int [2][4]' to
      parameter of type 'int *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    print_all(array, 2, 4);
              ^~~~~
arrays.c:4:22: note: passing argument to parameter 'array' here
void print_all(int * array, ptrdiff_t num_rows, ptrdiff_t num_cols) {
                     ^
1 warning generated.
```

Having `print_all` function only accept arrays with some specified number of columns is not acceptable.

Comment: If you want to pass a 2D array, why don't you pass one?? Respectively a pointer to a 1D array.

Comment: You are taking advantage of the contiguity of array elements in memory, but your function is expecting a `int *`, while you are passing an `int (*)[4]`. Call the function with a pointer of the proper type `print_all(array[0], 2, 4);` to make the warning disappear. Are you sure this is the code design you want to keep?

Answer (score 4):

If your compiler supports [variable length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (VLA), then you can do this

```
void print_all(ptrdiff_t num_rows, ptrdiff_t num_cols, int array[num_rows][num_cols]) {
    for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < num_rows; ++i) {
        for (ptrdiff_t j = 0; j < num_cols; ++j) {
            printf("%d\n", array[i][j]);
        }
    }
}


int main(void) {
    int array[2][4] = {
        {1, 2, 3, 4},
        {5, 6, 7, 8}
    };
    print_all(2, 4, array);
}
```

The `num_rows` and `num_cols` parameters must be before the `array` parameter so that the compiler knows the dimensions of the array. The VLA allows you to use 2D array indexing `array[i][j]` instead of doing the math yourself.

If you can't use VLAs or don't want to use VLAs, then the solution is simply to pass the address of the first element of the 2D array

```
print_all(&array[0][0], 2, 4);
```

Comment: @artm Section 6.5.6/9: *"When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements. The size of the result is implementation-defined, and its type (a signed integer type) is `ptrdiff_t` defined in the `<stddef.h>` header. If the result is not representable in an object of that type, the behavior is undefined."*

Comment: you mean we should use `ptrdiff_t` somewhere in this code; I don't see any pointer subtraction here?

Comment: @artm I mean that OP was correct to use `ptrdiff_t` as the type for `num_rows` and `num_cols`. Since the result of subtracting two array indexes must fit into a `ptrdiff_t`, it follows that the array indexes themselves must fit into a `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: @user3386109: No. `size_t` is the type which is guaranteed to hold the length of an array, so it is the correct type. It is the type returned by `sizeof` and used for `malloc`/`calloc` and friends.

Comment: @artm: For gcc <5 you have to specify `-std=c99` at least (or `c11`/`gnu*`)

Answer (score 2):

A 2D array is something like `int[rows][cols]`. So why not use the same syntax for the function parameter?

```
void print_all(size_t rows, size_t cols, int array[rows][cols]);
```

Notice using the correct types for the dimensions, which is not the signed `ptrdiff_t`, but `size_t`. You also have to declare the dimension paramters first so they are known for the array declaration.

Like for most usages of arrays, the name of the array is implicitly converted to a pointer to the first element, which is itself a 1D array: `int (*)[cols]`.

Use normal 2D index operators for the elements `array[r][c]`.

In the paramter declaration of the array the outer (`rows`) length is actually not required and can be omitted: `int array [][cols]`. But it is good practice to speccify it anyway, at least for documentation purposes.

The whole thing is much the same like for a *constant length array*. It is called a *variable length array* (VLA, for obvious reasons) and standard C since C99 (C11 made it optional, though, but any modern compiler should support it).

Use a constant length array with the macros below if you have an ancient compiler.

---

**Sidenote:**

Don't use magic numbers. Have the dimensions of the array in `main` defined as macros and use the macros only:

```
#define ROWS 2
#define COLS 4

...

int main(void)
{
    int array[ROWS][COLS] = ...;

    print_all(ROWS, COLS, array);
}
```

(I also used the correct signature of `main`; an empty parameterlist is deprecated and subject to be removed in a future version of the standard.)

That way you only have to change the macros if you want to change the lengths of the dimensions.

Comment: `num_rows` and `rows` - are they not supposed to be the same identifier? Same question for columns.

Comment: @CrabMan: See the edit (c/p flaw). I used the shorter names

Comment: Wow, it actually works. What magic is this? I don't think I've heard that you can do this `array[rows][cols]` thing where `rows` and `cols` are the other arguments.

Comment: @CrabMan: That is basically the same as for an array with constant lengths where you `#define ROWS 10`, etc. As I wrote, you just have to specify the variables you use for the dimensions before they are used. The compiler will use the expression in the `[]` then to calculate the lengths. I'll add a note.

Answer (score 1):

Your `print_all()` is accepting 1D array, but your `main` is parsing a 2D array, thus the warning.

You may keep your function intact, and change your `array` to 1D array, and it should work.

```
void print_all(int * array, ptrdiff_t num_rows, ptrdiff_t num_cols) {
    for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < num_rows; ++i) {
        for (ptrdiff_t j = 0; j < num_cols; ++j) {
            printf("%d\n", array[num_cols * i + j]);
        }
    }
}
```

and in `main()`

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
```

---

If you keep 2D array in `main`, then you'll need to change your `print_all()`

```
void print_all(int array[][4], ptrdiff_t num_rows) {
    for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < num_rows; ++i) {
        for (ptrdiff_t j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
            printf("%d\n", array[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

and in `main`

```
int array[][4] = {
    {1, 2, 3, 4},
    {5, 6, 7, 8}
};
```

You must provide the 2nd dimension (4), but can omit the 1st dimension (2); this is 2D array is stored a series of 1D array in memory.

Comment: OP did not use magic numbers, so why do you change that? Magic numbers are a very bad practice.

Answer (score -3):

Pointer is a pointer. You can ignore/suppress the warning as long as you know how to interpret it in the function.
Of course the preferred way of doing it is to use matching types on both ends.

Comment: That is dangerous nonsense!

Comment: Saying that something "dangerous nonsense" w/o specifics is nonsense. It is a) not any more dangerous than just working with pointers b) it is done all the time in good quality code. This is C we are talking about, not C++ with all casting operators and smart_pointers, etc.

Comment: If you really have to ask "why", you should read a C book and learn programming. Concentrate on the idea typed languages. Hint: correct code, type-checking, compiler as your friend, not your foe.

Comment: So, how do you propose it should be done? Sorry, I'm a bit out of date, been doing C for only 20 years.